# Python - Efficient way to calculate the Manhattan distance between each cell of a matrix?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, heuristics

I am trying to find the minimum number of hops to get from the value of one cell `w` to the value of another cell `v` in the following matrix `X` using Python.

Is there an efficient way to do this?

[image: manhattan distance for matrix]

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.typing import NDArray 


def manhattan_distance(X: NDArray[int], w: int, v: int) -> int:
     # something
     return distance
    

X = np.array([
    [1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
    [1, 2, 2, 4, 4],
    [5, 5, 6, 6, 6],
    [7, 8, 9, 9, 9],
    [10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
]).astype(np.int_)


# Expected result
manhattan_distance(X, 1, 2) # ①
-> 1
manhattan_distance(X, 2, 3) # ②
-> 1
manhattan_distance(X, 3, 6) # ③
-> 2
manhattan_distance(X, 3, 5) # ④
-> 4
```

I tried to implement it as follows, but it seems to be quite slow.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.typing import NDArray 

def manhattan_distance(X: NDArray[int], w: int, v: int) -> int:
    xx, yy = np.where(X == w)
    xx_, yy_ = np.where(X == v)
    distance = int(min_dist(xx, xx_) + min_dist(yy, yy_))
    return distance
  
def min_dist(xx, xx_):
    min_dist = np.inf
    for i in xx:
        for j in xx_:
            dist = np.sqrt((i - j)**2)
            min_dist = dist if dist < min_dist else min_dist
    return min_dist
```

Is there any way to speed this calculation up?

Comment: This is `dist = np.sqrt((i - j)**2)` is not the Manhattan distance

Comment: I think `int(min_dist(xx, xx_) + min_dist(yy, yy_))` is Manhattan distance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) to compute all pairwise distances, to find the values' indices use [`np.argwhere`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html)

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
import numpy as np
from numpy.typing import NDArray

X = np.array([
    [1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
    [1, 2, 2, 4, 4],
    [5, 5, 6, 6, 6],
    [7, 8, 9, 9, 9],
    [10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
]).astype(np.int32)


def manhattan_distance(X: NDArray[int], w: int, v: int) -> int:
    return cdist(np.argwhere(X == w), np.argwhere(X == v), "cityblock").min()


print(manhattan_distance(X, 1, 2))
print(manhattan_distance(X, 2, 3))
print(manhattan_distance(X, 3, 6))
print(manhattan_distance(X, 3, 5))
```

**Output**

```
1.0
1.0
2.0
4.0
```

Comment: This is very cool!!! However, the calculation time did not seem to improve much.

Comment: @ugen I've added answer that shows the calculation time does improve by much, but for small matrices it will hardly show

Comment: @dankal444 Yes, It's correct. It seems that I was wrong in my verification. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just adding timings for different matrix sizes to show OP that @Dani Mesejo answer indeed is much faster. For small matrices differences will be small of course.

```
def manhattan_distance_dani_masejo(X, w: int, v: int) -> int:
    return cdist(np.argwhere(X == w), np.argwhere(X == v), "cityblock").min()


def manhattan_distance_ugen(X, w: int, v: int) -> int:
    xx, yy = np.where(X == w)
    xx_, yy_ = np.where(X == v)
    distance = int(min_dist(xx, xx_) + min_dist(yy, yy_))
    return distance

def min_dist(xx, xx_):
    min_dist = np.inf
    for i in xx:
        for j in xx_:
            dist = np.sqrt((i - j)**2)
            min_dist = dist if dist < min_dist else min_dist
    return min_dist


def gen_data(matrix_size):
    return np.random.randint(0, matrix_size, (matrix_size, matrix_size), dtype=np.int32)

for matrix_size in [5, 50, 500]:
    print('Matrix size: {}'.format(matrix_size))
    X = gen_data(matrix_size)
    print('ugen: ', timeit.timeit("manhattan_distance_ugen(X, np.random.randint(0, matrix_size), np.random.randint(0, matrix_size))",
                        "from __main__ import manhattan_distance_ugen, X, matrix_size; import numpy as np",
                        number=10))
    print('dani masejo: ', timeit.timeit("manhattan_distance_dani_masejo(X, np.random.randint(0, matrix_size), np.random.randint(0, matrix_size))",
                        "from __main__ import manhattan_distance_dani_masejo, X, matrix_size; import numpy as np",
                        number=10))
```

Result:

```
Matrix size: 5
ugen:  0.0019634239999999914
dani masejo:  0.0006071939999999776
Matrix size: 50
ugen:  0.093326557
dani masejo:  0.0008874660000000034
Matrix size: 500
ugen:  9.112327058
dani masejo:  0.027754558000001595
```

Comment: I appreciate your cool verification.